# How to make the table fit better?

Tags: tables, math-mode, size, resize

**A suggestion by @mico: The OP has specified that this table should be generated by MathJax, which is off-topic for this site. I propose, though, to re-open this posting, by making the question about how to generate this table using (pdf)LaTeX. This table has enough formatting-related aspects to make having one or more solutions of potential interest to future readers.**

I made the [following table:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1910188/is-a-closed-form-version-of-the-look-and-say-sequence-useful)

[image]

As you can probably see, it is far too long... or wide or whatever.

```
$$\begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline & \text{Equality} & eq(x,y): & \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{B} & 1-|\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)| \\ 
\hline & \text{Digit At} & dat(x,b,i): & \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N} & \left\lfloor\frac{|x|}{b^i}\right\rfloor\mod b \\ 
\hline & \text{Number of Digits} & nd(x,b): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \lceil\log_b(x+1)\rceil \\
\hline & \text{Reverse} & rev(x,b): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \sum_{i=0}^{nd(x,b)-1}dat(x,b,I)\cdot10^{nd(x,b)-i-1} \\ 
\hline & \text{Sum Digits} & sd(x,b): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \sum_{i=0}^{nd(x,b)-1}dat(x,b,i)\\ 
\hline & \text{Look and Say Counter} & C_\lambda(x,i): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & sd(x\mod10^i,10) \\
\hline & \text{Unpadded Difference} & \delta(x): & \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \sum_{i=0}^{nd(x,10)-2}10^i\cdot(1-eq(dat(x,10,i),dat(x,10,i+1))) \\
\hline & \text{Padded Difference} & \Delta(x): & \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & 10^{nd(x,10)}+10\cdot\delta(x)+1 \\
\hline & \text{Leftmost Index} & il(x,i): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z} & nd(x\mod10^{i+1},10)-1 \\
\hline & \text{Rightmost Index} & ir(x,i): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z} & nd(x,10)-nd\left(rev\left(\left\lfloor\frac{x}{10^{i+1}}\right\rfloor,10\right),10\right) \\
\hline & \text{Look and Say} & L(x): & \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \sum_{i=0}^{nd(\Delta(x),10)-2}\left(dat(\Delta(x),10,i)\cdot\left(\left(ir(\Delta(x),i)-i\right)\cdot10^{1+2\cdot C_\lambda(\Delta(x),i)}+dat(x,10,i)\cdot10^{2\cdot C_\lambda(\Delta(x),i)}\right)\right)
\end{array}$$
```

Can I make this fit better?  Perhaps set a max width to each section and have it warp down when it hits that limiting size?

**EDIT:**

I have found that we can use /tiny or /small, but doing so reduces readability, which I would still like to have.

Comment: And how the preamble of document, by which we can test your table, is looking?

Comment: @Zarko It is quite to long to the right and kind of floating behind the meta and related questions area.

Comment: Your description doesn't help, this I estimated from your code. To help you, you need to help me/us with answer on my questions: which packages related to your table you have in preamble of document, used document class, page layout ... shortly: people, who wish to help you need a Minimal Working Example. Code snipped is not sufficient.

Comment: @Zarko Um... I'm sorry.  I'm kind of new to doing this and I pretty much don't understand what you asked me, so I can't answer in return.  Got a quick reference guide?

Comment: This isn't LaTeX. I would split the table and add serial number in both tables. But I guess, you should have asked [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Ben Ok, thanks.  Should I close this here then?

Comment: code seems (let forget how awful is written) look like latex. if it is not, than let closed question. apparently you miss SE site

Comment: @Zarko Take a look at his link in the first line. It's math.stackexchange code

Comment: Note to close-voters: it doesn't belong on TeX SE's meta-site either as it is not a question about **this** site. I has to be closed as off-topic I think. We can't send it to maths SE's meta, where I guess it belongs.

Comment: Thank you for your help and efforts, I have moved this question elsewhere: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24924/how-to-make-the-table-fit-better Or should I not have?

Comment: My link leads to math meta, doesn't it?

Comment: @cfr technically a moderator could do this and one could've flagged for one, but as it is already posted there by now, it's not worthy it anymore.

Comment: @Ben The reason for the first close vote linked it to TeX Meta.

Answer (score 4):

You can  have your table fit the margins in `landscape` orientation:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}%
\usepackage{lscape}%

 \usepackage{mathtools, amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{eq}
\DeclareMathOperator{\eq}{eq}
\DeclareMathOperator{\dat}{dat}
\DeclareMathOperator{\nd}{nd}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rev}{rev}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sd}{sd}
\DeclareMathOperator{\il}{il}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ir}{ir}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ls}{L}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{makecell} %
\setcellgapes{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
   \[ \makegapedcells\begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline & \text{Equality} & \eq(x,y): & \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{B} & 1-|\sgn(x-y)| \\
\hline %
& \text{Digit At} & \dat(x,b,i): & \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N} & \floor*{\dfrac{\abs{x}}{b^i}}\mod b \\
\hline %
& \text{Number of Digits} & \nd(x,b): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \ceil{\log_b(x+1)} \\
\hline%
 & \text{Reverse} & \rev(x,b): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \displaystyle \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{i=0}^{\nd(x,b)-1}}\dat(x,b,I)\cdot10^{\nd(x,b)-i-1} \\
\hline%
 & \text{Sum Digits} & \sd(x,b): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \displaystyle\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{i=0}^{\nd(x,b)-1}}\dat(x,b,i)\\
\hline%
 & \text{Look and Say Counter} & C_\lambda(x,i): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \sd(x\mod10^i,10) \\
\hline %
& \text{Unpadded Difference} & \delta(x): & \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \displaystyle\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{i=0}^{\nd(x,10)-2}}10^i\cdot(1-\eq(\dat(x,10,i),\dat(x,10,i+1))) \\
\hline %
& \text{Padded Difference} & \Delta(x): & \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & 10^{\nd(x,10)}+10\cdot\delta(x)+1 \\
\hline%
 & \text{Leftmost Index} &\il(x,i): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z} & \nd(x\mod10^{i+1},10)-1 \\
\hline %
& \text{Rightmost Index} & \ir(x,i): & \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z} & \nd(x,10)-\nd\left(\rev\left(\floor{\dfrac{x}{10^{i+1}}},10\right),10\right) \\
\hline%
 & \text{Look and Say} & \ls(x): & \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} & \begin{multlined}\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{i=0}^{\nd(\Delta(x),10)-2}}\dat(\Delta(x),10,i) \cdot\left(\left(\ir(\Delta(x),i)-i\right)\cdot10^{1+2\cdot C_\lambda(\Delta(x),i)}\right. \\[-4.5ex] \left.{}+\dat(x,10,i)\cdot10^{2\cdot C_\lambda(\Delta(x),i)}\right)
 \end{multlined}\\
 \hline
\end{array}
    \]
\end{landscape}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I try to put this in math.SE, it says "unknown environment 'landscape'"

Comment: If you can post the actual code of the image with the special symbols around it and stuff instead of an image, I think I can figure out how to produce the same results.  I hope.

Comment: ^^??? The code corresponds to the image. What do you mean?

Comment: I just don't know how to make it come out as an image.

Comment: Oh, note that I'm doing this in math.SE, so all the defining operators can be safely ignored.  I left the operators as letters since that's how the OP wanted it.

Comment: That makes them more difficult to read: they're italic and the spacing is not very good. As to the image, it's just a screenshot of the .pdf produced by the compilation. B.t.w. you can use `\DeclareMathOperator` on MathSE (but not a full preamble, as far as I know).

Comment: @SimpleArt That image is not rendered with MathJax but with pdfLaTeX. The image is just a screenshot of the PDF which results from compiling the posted code off-site. MathJax is not enabled on TeX SE. We don't use it. It isn't TeX. This is why your question is off-topic for this site ;) - you can see how confusing it gets!

Comment: @cfr Quite indeed.  Thank you for the clarification.  Maybe I'll figure out what Bernard's answer meant someday, it seems interesting (because sometimes I go to the math.SE site just to type something up and take a pic of it ;-)   )

Comment: @SimpleArt Have you tried OverLeaf or ShareLaTeX? It seems like that would be easier ....

Comment: @cfr Well, no.  Just math.SE's TeX.  Would be nice to not have to pull up math.SE to do special typing.